# Как в Laravel добавить кастумный путь к api?

Tags: laravel

Хочу написать API, но по задумке хочу использовать 2 разных маршрута, например стандартный путь: localhost/api/home... а также, например: localhost/admin/home... и чтобы эти пути работали параллельно. Как создать еще один router api со своим именем, как в примере "admin" и в нем уже реализовать логику приложения отдельно от дефолтного api?

Comment: Удалил предыдущий ответ.. так как он по сути был приколом над вами... задам другой( в чем у вас возникла сложность при реализации вашего плана?  ..
P.S... ошибку вставьте в вопрос :) надеюсь понятно.. да и.. api и web это разное.. ознакомьтесь с доками